# fill() method for object type

Tags: javascript

Javascript has `Array.prototype.fill()` method for Arrays, but what about objects? if we have something like this:

```
let obj ={
  a: true,
  b: 'Hi Dude',
  c: 12
}
```

is there any built-in method to fill all properties with one value and make it like this:

```
let obj ={
  a: 'goodbye Dude',
  b: 'goodbye Dude',
  c: 'goodbye Dude'
}
```

I know `forEach()` or `for...in` solutions can do that, but I hope it can be done with a better approach.

Comment: What's wrong with `Object.keys()` plus `.forEach()`?

Comment: And would `{a: {b: 'Hi Dude'}, c:12}` turn into `{a: 'goodbye Dude', c:'goodbye Dude'}` or `{a: {b: 'goodbye Dude'}, c: 'goodbye Dude'}`?

Comment: @Pointy nothing wrong, maybe this is the best solution.

Comment: @ScottSauyet simplest object. just `{a: 'goodbye Dude', c:'goodbye Dude'}`

Comment: I'm with @31piy: What is this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one for objects because the properties of objects are not uniform (not like indexes of an array which we know goes from `0` to `length - 1`).

But you can implement what you need using `Object.keys` and `Array#forEach`:

```
Object.keys(theObject).forEach(function(key) {
    theObject[key] = theValue;
});
```

which is even shorter using an arrow function:

```
Object.keys(theObject).forEach(key => theObject[key] = theValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

If by any chance the object is from JSON, the values can also be changed with `JSON.parse`:

```js
j = '{ "a": true, "b": "Hi Dude", "c": 12 }'

o = JSON.parse(j, (k, v) => k === '' ? v : 'goodbye Dude')

console.log( o )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid mutating your original object, you can do it like this:

```
const fill = val => obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((o, k) => ({...o, [k]: val}), {})

const obj = {a: true, b: 'Hi Dude', c: 12}
fill('goodbye Dude')(obj) //=> {a: 'goodbye Dude', b: 'goodbye Dude', c: 'goodbye Dude'}
obj //=> {a: true, b: 'Hi Dude', c: 12}
```

Of course you can change the signature to `(val, obj) => ...` and call it like `fill('goodbye Dude', obj)`, but it might be useful to have it curried.